# Finding an element of specific order

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Consider $F_{17^*}$ , the multiplicative group of $F_{17}$. Find an element $α$ of order 16 in this group. List those elements that have order 4 as powers of $α$.

Attempt:

I know that in any group, an element and its inverse have the same order, and from Fermat little theorem,
$α^{16} = 1 (mod17)$

but that's about it

Comment: Hint. Trial and error. Calculate the orders of 2, 3, ... . Stop when you find one of order 16. There's a theorem that says that will happen.

Comment: $17$ is special in that any quadratic non-residue is a generator. So half the numbers from $1$ to $16$ will work.

Comment: For order $4$, either calculate patiently, or use the fact that if $g$ is a generator, the order of $g^k$ is $16/\gcd(k,16)$.

Comment: Thanks i got the first part now, what is $g$ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Since for all $\;x\in\Bbb F_{17}^*\;$ we have $\;x^{16}=1\;$ , you have only to check $\;x^2,x^4, x^8\;$ . If none of this is one then you have your element.

Comment: It's more efficient to just check $x^8 \neq 1$, if it does equal $1$, check another $x$.

Comment: @DavidWheeler Thank you, you are right.